# Appengine and Markdown resulting in spaced-out text: < p > W o r d < / p >

Tags: python, google-app-engine, markdown

I am having problem to get a right render to html with markdown. I am using 
[python-markdown](http://freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown) in appengine 2.7

My question is I am getting to many spaces between the characters in the HTML - namespace? Like this `< code >code< / code >`.

Here is my Class:

```
class Text(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        text = self.request.get('content')
        html = markdown.markdown(text)

        template_values = {'html': html}
```

Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
</head>
<body>
    {% for html in html %}
        {{ html }}
    {% endfor %}  
</body>
</html>
```

Here one more sample of what is going on:

```
# Word
```

becomes:

```
< h 1 >Word< / h 1 >
```

Answer (score 3):

You are interpreting the HTML returned as a list; by looping over text you create individual characters:

```
>>> for ch in 'sample':
...     print ch,
s a m p l e
```

Just interpolate the `html` variable directly:

```
<body>
    {{ html }}
</body>
```